# PHP Module with incorrect compiled API (unable to initialize)

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to install freetds and php-mssql on a RHEL5 box.  I've successfully done (what appears to be) everything.  However, I get the following error when PHP attempts to load the module:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mssql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20050922, debug=0, thread-safety=0
These options need to match
```

I've been pulling my brain out trying to figure out why they are different values, but having no success.

In the latest attempt, I downloaded the php source for the version I am running (php-5.3.8), went into the ext/mssql folder and ran phpize, configure, make, make install.

I verified the mssql.so file is in the appropriate folder, and that php is trying to load it.

```
phpize -v
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20050922
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

RHEL had an older version of php (5.1.x), and the installation of newer php versions (such as 5.3.x) means several changes. If you install from unofficial repos, you will see packages named php-* and php5-* . Having both versions can be the origin of the problems.

It looks like your system is accessing some configuration files from previous php installations.

Have a look at:
 - /etc/php.d Be sure you do not have elements from old versions
 - Have a look at /usr/bin/php-config* , If you have both php-config and php-config5, remove (rename) of /usr/bin/php-config and make a symlink to the new one:

```
# mv /usr/bin/php-config /usr/bin/php-config_old
# ln -s /usr/bin/php-config5 /usr/bin/php-config
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I was starting to theorize that there may be two versions of php installed. I did notice that php-config says version="5.1.6", but php -v displays version as 5.3.8. No php-config5 file exists.

Comment: Where can I find the newer version of php-config if it doesn't exist in /usr/bin?  Would I need to do a new install of php 5.3.8 (which is what php is running) to copy over php-config?

Comment: Thanks very much, this was giving me headaches. I was trying to setup memcached on osx but kept having this problem. Eventually I used pecl to install 'pecl install memcached' once I had corrected the php, phpize and php-config versions to the ones supplied by MAMP

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that when a module doesn't load because of a different API it's because of an old php-config. Then you must look in /usr/bin/php-config and overwrite it with a newer version.

Comment: Thanks David. Do you have a suggestion on how to proceed (in reference to comment on prior answer left)

Comment: @AndrewVogel: I've found new php-config in php folder but I've installed php from a tarball. I think the old php-config is from a remote install like apt-get. I got the same problem with eaccelarator. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes.. which folder did you have the new php-config? Or was that in your /usr/bin folder as jap1968 indicated? If I don't have a newer php-config anywhere, I suppose my only option would be doing a fresh install of php?

Comment: @AndrewVogel: php-5.3.8/scripts/php-config. I'm using a tarball and I'm not using RHEL and in my /usr/bin there isn't a php-config5.

Comment: I am having this same issue, yet /usr/bin/        there is only one php-config any suggestions?

Comment: @Betterdev   I downloaded the latest version, but what fixed it, i restarted my laptop.

Comment: Ok i found this file  /usr/bin/php-config  but no matter what i did I could not edit it. I am using High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you using debian based distributions, Ubuntu for example, you can also check for any alternatives that have been set, in the case that you have installed more than one version of php.

One way to quickly determine which alternatives have been set for anything related to php is to `ls -l /etc/alternatives/*php*`

Example output:

```
$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/*php*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 May 19 00:02 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php7.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jan 28 18:50 /etc/alternatives/php-cgi -> /usr/bin/php-cgi7.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Jan 28 18:50 /etc/alternatives/php-cgi-bin -> /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jan 28 18:50 /etc/alternatives/php-cgi.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/php-cgi7.4.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 May 19 20:27 /etc/alternatives/php-config -> /usr/bin/php-config7.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38 May 19 20:27 /etc/alternatives/php-config.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/php-config7.4.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 May 19 20:30 /etc/alternatives/php-fpm.sock -> /run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 May 19 00:02 /etc/alternatives/php.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/php7.4.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 May 19 20:29 /etc/alternatives/phpdbg -> /usr/bin/phpdbg7.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 May 19 20:29 /etc/alternatives/phpdbg.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/phpdbg7.4.1.gz
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 May 19 20:29 /etc/alternatives/phpize -> /usr/bin/phpize7.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 May 19 20:29 /etc/alternatives/phpize.1.gz -> /usr/share/man/man1/phpize7.4.1.gz
```

In my case, I had installed php8 after having 7.4 already installed.  Then I needed to switch back, half of my alternatives were still set to 8. When I tried to enable an extension that I had installed with pecl, then I experienced the issue mentioned by OP.

So, for example, when switching from php 8.0 back to 7.4, if the symbolic  link for one of the alternatives is still pointing to 8.0, say `php-fpm.sock`, then you would
`sudo update-alternatives --config php-fpm.sock` and choose the number of the selection match php7.4-fpm.sock (1 in the example below)

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config php-fpm.sock 
There are 2 choices for the alternative php-fpm.sock (providing /run/php/php-fpm.sock).

  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock   80        auto mode
  1            /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock   74        manual mode
  2            /run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock   80        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```