# FFMPEG Error, any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Tags: php, apache, ffmpeg, xampp

Hello i have installed xampp on my windows computer and running it as a home server, i want to install ffmpeg and it keeps coming up with an error and ive looked everywhere but found nothing! any ideas of whats going on and how to fix this?

The image of the error - http://fktwtv.sytes.net/error.png

Comment: Your image link is timing out for me. You should include all relevant information within your question and provide the actual text instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple related questions that may provide some more info:
[php-module-with-incorrect-compiled-api-unable-to-initialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406743/php-module-with-incorrect-compiled-api-unable-to-initialize)
[apache-is-unable-to-initialize-module-because-of-modules-and-phps-api-dont](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394532/apache-is-unable-to-initialize-module-because-of-modules-and-phps-api-dont)

Basically, PHP and all of the modules must be compiles with the same API.  If you've installed from package, check for a version of the package that matches your version of php.